# Swift 2.2 AnyObject Type

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift2

After the update of iOS 9.3 and the new update for Swift 2.2 (at least that was stated in the Xcode update changes) the code below doesn't work for me anymore.

```
if context[indexPath.row].dynamicType.className() == "MyClass"
```

it throws an exception which states:

```
Value of type 'AnyObject.Type' has no member 'className'
```

I am going through the changes which are described in [swift.org](https://swift.org/blog/swift-2-2-released/) but I can't find the answer of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what `className()` does.  It's not a known method on `AnyClass`.

There are a few ways you can fix this.

Use `description()` to get a String description of the class name:

```
if context[indexPath.row].dynamicType.description() == "MyClass" {
    // ...
}
```

Or if you're using Objective-C types you can use `NSClassFromString` to return an `AnyClass` from a String:

```
if context[indexPath.row].dynamicType == NSClassFromString("MyClass") {
    // ...
}
```

Swift 3:

`dynamicType` has been renamed to `type(of:)`.  Usage:

```
type(of: context[indexPath.row]) == MyClass.self
```

or

```
context[indexPath.row] is MyClass
```

Comment: Thank you! Its working.I wanted to make sure if the object is from type "MyClass" or if not... you get the code but I have no idea why it was working before if you don't know what its doing :D My object type was AnyObject :)

Answer (score 3):

Why bother with Strings when you have true compiler support in the type system itself?  I recommend instead:

```
if context[indexPath.row].dynamicType == MyClass.Type.self {
    // ...
}
```

Also, it's quite likely that you really mean:

```
if let cell = context[indexPath.row] as? MyClass {
    // ...
}
```

unless you're intent on cutting out derived classes forever.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! :)

Comment: This doesn't work if you don't have an explicit reference to `MyClass` (using reflection, etc.)  But yes, this is cleaner since it cuts out the Strings.